# How to use ternary operator in String concatenation, to check length of String

Tags: jasper-reports

Code:

```
"No. Siri Pendaftaran : " + ($F{ref_no}.length() > 10) ? $F{ref_no} : $F{ref_no}.substring(0,20)+ "..."
```

Error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean
>
> Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:

Comment: Code should not be posted as images, but as text and put in code tags.

Comment: ok, @Jure check again. i updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if-else-if-else in textfield expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677675/if-else-if-else-in-textfield-expression)

Comment: The difference can be that this is String concatenation, user in question has included code as in answer on duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ternary operator in String concatenation you need to include `()` around the expression so that it can be evaluated correctly

This will work

```
"No. Siri Pendaftaran : " + (($F{ref_no}.length() > 10) ? $F{ref_no} : $F{ref_no}.substring(0,20))+ "..."
```

Saying this I think you are looking for this expression

```
"No. Siri Pendaftaran : " + (($F{ref_no}.length() <= 10) ? $F{ref_no} : ($F{ref_no}.substring(0,10)+ "..."))
```

Comment: @FaridBlaster, thanks for accepted I have update my answer, since your expression seems strange... (to not only solve your compilation problem)

Comment: btw, it actual code i changed and it solved :

(($F{ref_no}.size() > 40 ? $F{ref_no}.substring(0,40)+ "..." : $F{ref_no}))