# Jaspersoft Studio error : Type mismatch : cannot convert from boolean to boolean

Tags: jasper-reports

I figure out Jaspersoft Studio and i'am trying to build a report.
But when i click on "preview" to launch my report, i've this error:

" **Type mismatch : cannot convert from boolean to boolean**" then when i click on this error, jasper open my expression editor: "1.3.  " + ($P{Langue_francais} ? "Date de naissance" : "Date, Place, Country of Birth")

Expression:

[image: My Expression]

The parameter $P{Langue_francais} called in this expression  is here:

Parameter's definition:

[image: The parameter]

There is someone who can help me with this.

Comment: Duplicates [How to use ternary operator in String concatenation, to check length of String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35173279/876298)

Comment: This not help me

Comment: You should post the small *jrxml* to reproduce the issue

Comment: Hi alex i've solve my probleme.

Comment: but when i launch the report on JasperStudion version 6.10,  i've this error message:

 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
    Source text : $P{Langue_francais} ? $F{appreciations_fr}!=null && !$F{appreciations_fr}.equals("") : $F{appreciations_an}!=null && !$F{appreciations_an}.equals("")



Could you help me with this?

Sincerely

Comment: My Source code: