# How to use Case statement in report?

Tags: jasper-reports

Can anyone let me know how to write a CASE STATEMENT like in SQL but in a Jaspersoft 6 report? More precisely inside the expression editor.

For example:

```
CASE ProductLine  
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'  
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'  
         WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'  
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'  
         ELSE 'Not for sale'  
END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if-else-if-else in textfield expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677675/if-else-if-else-in-textfield-expression)

Comment: You can use ternary operator

Comment: Alex, thanks for replying but not sure how to use it for in my case we are dealing with more than 3 case statements ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ternary operator like below:

```
$F{variable_1}.equals("R") == true ? 'Road' : "Else not for Sale"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't use case directly but having if else condition within another if else condition will give the solution.

Here's an example below where the switch-case functionality is achieved through multiple if else conditions

```
( $F{FIELDV}.equals("ab") ? "aaaa" :
    ( $F{FIELDV}.equals("bc") ? "bbbb" :
         ( $F{FIELDV}.equals("de") ? "cccc" : ""  
)))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it