# What does the ? symbol mean after the first IF statement?

Tags: jasper-reports, conditional-operator

new Here! I'm working on Jaspersoft, I've never used it before, but I saw some guide about.
I know that the IF condition has this structure :   `<condition> ?(Then) True :(else) False`.
But I have problem to understand this line of code (see at the end of this message), where the IF is a little bit complicated. Can someone explain me what this line of code does?

```
($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() == (1+("".equals($P{parametriReport}.get("censimp"))?0:1)) ? ("".equals($P{parametriReport}.get("censimp"))?"":"Codice Censimp "+$P{parametriReport}.get("censimp")):"")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if-else-if-else in textfield expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677675/if-else-if-else-in-textfield-expression)

Comment: [Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)